# EF Navigation Properties and Saves

Tags: entity-framework

Suppose I have these two POCOs:

```
   public class Album {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public short Rating { get; set; }
      public int ArtistID { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
   }

   public class Artist {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }
   }
```

and then I execute some code like this:

```
    using (PickContext db=new PickContext()) {
       Album pick=db.Albums.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ID==pickID);
       if (pick==null) return;
       pick.Rating=4;
       db.SaveChanges();
```

I was surprised that I got a validation exception like this:

> Property: "Artist", Error: "The Artist field is required."

When I changed my query to include the Artist:

```
       Album pick=db.Albums.Include("Artist").SingleOrDefault(a => a.ID==pickID);
```

I no longer got the exception.  If I don't tell EF to populate all properties, and they're not required, will it simply overwrite these FKs in the database?  I would have thought that if I retrieve an entity and don't assign a property, the property won't be changed in the database.  Is this not true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the required attribute for the Artist. It simply telling to EF your navigation property is always required to be there. Since you have defined,

```
public int ArtistID { get; set; }
```

as not nullable the ArtistID  will be required in the in the database level (I think that is what you expected from the required attribute here). I think you can just remove the required attribute and then this should be working as expected.